# What is the short way of writing this validation Error code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using error validation on my Windows Forms and if there is a simple and short way of writing this code please share with me. Thanks.

**Here is the Code:**

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSrcUserID.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtSrcUserID, "Please enter Source User_ID");
                return;                
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSrcUserPassword.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtSrcUserPassword, "Please enter Source Password");
                return;                
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSrcUserDatabase.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtSrcUserDatabase, "Please enter Source Database");
                return;               
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTrgUserID.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtTrgUserID, "Please enter Target User_ID");
                return;              
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDesPassword.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(txtDesPassword, "Please enter Target Password");
                return;               
            }
```

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could put all the controls and error messages into a `List<Tuple<Control, string>>` and then `foreach` over that.

Comment: Why you return instead of validating all fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this

```
public class ControlValidationInfo
{
    public Control Control { get; set; }
    public string EmptyTextErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

ControlValidationInfo[] infos = new []{ new ControlValidationInfo{ Control = txtSrcUserID, EmptyTextErrorMessage  = "Please enter Source User_ID"}}; // add all in this array

foreach(var info in infos)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(info.Control.Text))
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(info.Control , info.EmptyTextErrorMessage);
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to ----// add all in this array?

Comment: @user2760129 Just put an instance of `ControlValidationInfo` for each of your controls in there, following the one example.

Comment: @user2760129 As I've added for `txtSrcUserID` you've to add for all other controls like `txtSrcUserPassword` etc

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, getting error can you show it second validation txtSrcUserPassword inside the array?